# What is the point of low end discrete gpu in laptops?

Tags: laptop, gpu

i have an Lenovo g40-80, which has an i5-5200u cpu and an amd r5 m330 gpu. To my surprise when i checked the performance of the igpu on 5200u and the m330 gpu, they have similar performance, what is the point of that low end discrete gpu other than using more electricity than the igpu?

another one would have i7-7500u with r7 m440 gpu, which the gpu performs worse than the igpu on the 7500u cpu, it seems to me that low end discrete gpu on laptop are pointless other than increasing the price.

Comment: It depends on what you are running and your needs. I gave up on that and use only high end Intel integrated GPU for my needs . Works well. To you point on electricity, my two laptops each draw 11 watts.

Comment: Increasing the price isn’t “useless” to the seller

Comment: iGPUs typically have a great deal less VRAM compared to even comparable mobile dGPUs

Comment: @Ramhound but only in higher end cards, my 5200u igpu has 2gb vram and the amd r5 m330 also has 2gb vram

Comment: @Quartz2 - Your iGPU shares your system memory, while the dGPU, has its own 2GB VRAM

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons you might want a integrated and discrete gpu. Load balancing, encoding, bufferring, post processing...multiple monitors (on a budget) and more.

I have a Surface Book 2 and it has dual graphic cards. The docking keyboard has a "beefier" GPU that becomes the primary system graphics adapter so it can handle more resource intensive demands. The tablet portion has its own integrated graphics adapter for the purpose of being able to....well tablet.